# How to run a loop to fetch a data from multi chekboxes in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm trying to fetch a data from checkboxes but it gives me the error:

```
"Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\blogger\wp-content\themes\blogger\single-book.php on line 16"
```

i tried this code:

**function.php**

```
    $books->add_field(array(
            'id'         => 'select',
            'name'       => 'This is a checkboxes',
       //   'desc'       => 'How to Train Your Dragon Story',
            'type'    => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
            'check1' => 'Check One',
            'check2' => 'Check Two',
            'check3' => 'Check Three',
        ),

        ));
```

**index.php**

```
     <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'select',true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using CMB2 plugin, your code
`<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'select',true); ?>`
will return an array with the values. Only checked values will come. In your code `get_the_ID()` is wrongly called **id** should be in **capital**.

```
    $vals= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'select',true); 
    foreach ($vals as $key => $v) {
        echo $v;
    }
```

Hope this will work for you,

Comment: Thank you sooooo much @tristup it is working perfect

Comment: great it helps you.

Comment: Yes ofcourse u gave me the exact code what i wanted . Again thanks